# Unusual funding issue -- what are my good next steps?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, graduate-school, funding

So I got some strange news last week, and I'm hoping someone knows what a good next move in my situation is. I'm an MSci CS student in the U.K., about to graduate.

A while back I got an offer to continue my masters studies in a PhD programme I applied to, at my current university. More recently, I heard that some friends who had also applied had heard back about funding many weeks ago. I did some asking around and found that my funding application never got considered -- due to an administrative error, my funding application was never processed, though I did submit it within the deadline. All funding has now been distributed, but I never had a shot at funding from the school's DTC as a result of this error.

...I have a potential fallback. A company is interested in sponsoring my research -- they'll put 50% toward the fees and living expenses, and the college pays the other 50%. I'm yet to hear back about this from the college's end, but the company has already committed. Note that this funding's coming from the college of science and engineering, of which the CS school is a part -- so the funding can come from two places.

Obviously, I want to maximise my chances of getting out of this scenario with funding. Less obvious is how to go about getting that best shot! With the issue I'm facing regarding DTC funding being kind of unique, I'm not sure that anyone knows what the protocol is. That means I don't know what it'll be possible to make happen. Some suggestions I've had:

1. There's always the college funding and the industrial application I've got right now.
2. Using this situation as leverage to try to get the school, rather than the college, to fund the other 50% of the industrial application. This is my prospective supervisor's bet.
3. As a new tax year brings a new budget, there's potentially a new pool of funding for the DTC for the coming year. I wonder whether I can be considered now for funding from this new pool. Not sure whether that would then affect my start date.
4. Defer my entry until October 2018 and apply again to the DTC in the coming year. This was the suggested course of action from the admin assistant who made the error -- its also my lowest preference.

Does anyone have an idea as to whether the school is obligated to consider me at all, if I've applied for funding with my admission application? And what might I be able to do to improve my chances? Does anyone have advice on which if the above might be avenues worth exploring?

Thanks!

Comment: I'd try escalating it further up in the admin chain (potentially a formal complaint to the dean). Whether or not the school is obligated to reconsider you, this reflects very badly on them. Also, can't you try to pursue all of the above options simultaneously?

Comment: I think (2) is your best shot. If that fails, then take the 50% to another university.

Comment: @OlgaK escalation hadn't even occurred to me! That's a good idea, thank you. I certainly could pursue all of the options -- and I will! -- but it's also exam & dissertation & flat moving time, so I don't have a ton of time to dedicate, and knowing where my best chances might lie just helps to direct me.

Comment: @user2768 Thank you! 2 sounds like a plan to me, too, so that's encouraging... news today is that they might actually have some funding to make that happen, so I might be in luck. Thanks for your advice!

Comment: Do try to lay a guilt trip on them (lay the problem at their doorstep).  You can ask them to give you a clear answer to the question, "If my application had been processed, how would I have fared?"